# Having trouble getting a hover function to work on this code

Tags: jquery

So I need to be able to hover over the face in #3 and it changes to the gooey face and back, but it just won/t work

```
<section id="three">
<p class="desc">3. Create a hover event that will change the image from happy to gooey (and back again) then create a double click event that will change the image to angry.</p>
<img src="images/happyface.png" alt="face">
```

```
       `$("three img").hover(function(){
        $(this).attr({src:"images/gooeyface.png"})
       }),
       function(){
        $(this).attr({src:"images/happyface.png"});
       };`
```

Comment: `$("three img")` -> `$("#three img")`

Comment: nvmd, I got it, sorry peeps

Comment: Thank you Anurag, took me a while to figure it out. They are teaching us HTML, CSS, Javascript AND JQuery all in the same semester. I am going bonkers.

Answer (score 0):

Add `#three img` in your code instead of `three img` because here `three` is an id and `id`'s are written as follows

```
 $("three img").hover(function(){
        $(this).attr({src:"images/gooeyface.png"})
       }),
       function(){
        $(this).attr({src:"images/happyface.png"});

       };
```

Answer (score 0):

Selector is missing  '#'
Use this
$("#three img")